# Trying to sort struct but it isnt working?

Tags: c++, sorting, struct

The function is supposed to sort the users by their total money from their deposits but it ain't working properly, I am sure that it is not from the variables as it is still displaying what it needs to but not sorted, where am I wrong?

```
    
    for(int i = 0; i < *br; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < l[i].numofdep; j++)l[i].total += l[i].dep[j].value;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < *br - 1; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < *br - 1; j++)
    {
        if(l[j].total > l[j+1].total)
        {
            int in = l[j].no;
            l[j].no = l[j+1].no;
            l[j+1].no = in;
            
            string str = l[j].fname;
            l[j].fname = l[j+1].fname;
            l[j+1].fname = str;
            
            str = l[j].lname;
            l[j].lname = l[j+1].lname;
            l[j+1].lname = str;
            
            in = l[j].numofdep;
            l[j].numofdep = l[j+1].numofdep;
            l[j+1].numofdep = in;
            
            for(int k = 0; k < l[i+1].numofdep; k++)
            {
                in = l[j].dep[k].value;
                l[j].dep[k].value = l[j+1].dep[k].value;
                l[j+1].dep[k].value = in;
                
                str = l[j].dep[k].currency;
                l[j].dep[k].currency = l[j+1].dep[k].currency;
                l[j+1].dep[k].currency = str;
                
                in = l[j].dep[k].dd;
                l[j].dep[k].dd = l[j+1].dep[k].dd;
                l[j+1].dep[k].dd = in;
                
                in = l[j].dep[k].mm;
                l[j].dep[k].mm = l[j+1].dep[k].mm;
                l[j+1].dep[k].mm = in;
                
                in = l[j].dep[k].yy;
                l[j].dep[k].yy = l[j+1].dep[k].yy;
                l[j+1].dep[k].yy = in;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: I don't see `std::sort`. Is the goal to implement a sorting function, or just to get things sorted?

Comment: Tip: `std::swap` instead of all this manual variable swapping. 95% of this code doesn't even need to exist. Most of it would go away if you implemented a comparator that `std::sort` can deal with, or you had a comparison function instead.

Comment: Whatever type of objects the `l` array contains, you should rely on its assignment operator instead of manually swapping all the members.

Comment: Also why are you not using a `struct` to hold the data?  Then it's just a single array of that `struct` instead of 5 (or more) separate arrays you have to juggle.  What if there were 15 or 20 items associated with the user?  You would write 20 swaps?

Comment: This is completely unreadable.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The best part is... he/she _is_ using a `struct` to hold the data! They're not 5 separate arrays; they're 5 members of each element of 1 array. For some reason the swap is being performed _outside_ the type, hence the repetition.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Yes, I see that now.   Makes my point even more pertinent.  If that struct contained 50 items, I guess 50 swaps would have been written :).  Also, single letter variable names like `l` does make the code practically unreadable.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yep 

Comment: It is in an array of struct, the first bit of the function isn't here(which itself is to sort the array that's in main) as the site said that it is too much code and little explanation. I will fix the swapping but can you explain why the sorting isn't working, that condition is right isn't it? first i am combining the sum of all deposits of a person then sorting by that?

Comment: If you fixed the swapping, possibly the sorting will magically fix itself.  Or better yet -- show us the `l` struct, and only the struct, nothing else, and then we can see what you are sorting.  The sort you've written is almost illegible (already mentioned).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this is the struct - https://prnt.sc/vzaq5v

Comment: Please post the struct in the original post as text, not as an image.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the site is not lettign me *there is too much code*

Answer (score 2):

If this is homework, which it looks like it is, and you're not able to use the standard library just quite yet, take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) for a good explanation of how to write an insertion sort. That'll solve your problem as I can tell from the general structure of your code that's what you're trying to accomplish, but there's too much indexing into sub-arrays for me to make out what's going wrong at a glance other than your general loop structure is wrong.

Comment: It doesn't look like much, but sometimes the best answer is "Don't waste your time fixing it. Chuck it out and start over."

Comment: @user4581301 or that he's not using {};s. lol